# Store only numbers on an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, double, store

I have a class Cliente that has an ArrayList which stores the classes Jamon, Cereal, etc in it. This classes (Jamon, Cereal, etc) are extened from a superclass called Producto. 
What I need is an array (besides the Array List) which ONLY stores the precios(double) of each class. This is in order to add them together with a for cycle.
This are my codes

The code for the class Cliente:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Cliente extends Persona{
    public List<Producto>products=new ArrayList<Producto>();

    public void echarAlCarrito(Producto p){
        products.add(p);
    }
}
```

The code for the class Producto:

```
public abstract class Producto{
protected double precio;

public void setPrecio(double precio){
    this.precio=precio;
}

public double getPrecio(){
    return precio;
}

abstract void comprar(Cliente c);


}
```

The code for the Jamon class

```
public class Jamon extends Producto implements Refrigerable{
protected String marca;

public Jamon(String marca, Double precio){
    this.marca=marca;
    this.precio=precio;
}

public void setMarca(String marca){
    this.marca=marca;
}
public String getMarca(){
    return marca;
}

public void comprar(Cliente c){
    System.out.println("El cliente ha comprado el jamon");
}

}
```

And the code for my main:

```
public class PruebaSupermercado{
double suma;

public static void verCarrito() {
    Cliente zoo = new Cliente();
    zoo.echarAlCarrito(new Jamon("Fud",15.3));
    zoo.echarAlCarrito(new Ropa("GAP",457.5));
    zoo.echarAlCarrito(new Cereal("Nestle",36.2));
    Cliente hola = new Cliente();
    for (Producto a:zoo.products){
        a.comprar(hola);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    verCarrito();
}
}
```

The cereal and ropa class look exactly the same (except the name and such) as Jamon.

So yeah.. my question is "How do i make and array in Cliente that ONLY contains the precios of each Jamon, Cereal, Ropa class?"

Thank you

Comment: Do you want an array of prices grouped by **class** (Jamon, Cereal, Ropa) or an array that contains the prices of all the Products in the Carrito (the **instances**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Double> precios = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (Producto p: products) {
    precios.add(p.getPrecio());
}
```

Or this, if you really need an array:

```
double[] precios = new double[products.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
    precios[i] = products.get(i).getPrecio();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use every class implementing the List interface, but since you can't store double (the primitive type) you will have to use Double. It's simple do get a Double from a double, using the [Double.valueof(double d)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29) method of the Double class.

If you really want to stick to the double primitive type you'll have to use a primitive array.